# renaming IDs in gff3 with BCBio.GFF

Tags: sequence-annotation, python, gff3

I wrote a script which should changes IDs in a GFF3 file. Unfortunately, the below script has two problems.

1. It attaches the new ID to `Parent` which leads that `Parent` contains the old and new id. How is it possible to keep only the new one?
2. How is it possible to access the chromosome name?

This how to run the script `python renameIDgff3.py --gff3 braker_utr.gff3 --prefix ACTG --output braker_utr-newID.gff3`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import click
from BCBio.GFF import GFFExaminer
from BCBio import GFF

@click.command()
@click.option('--gff3', help="Provide GFF3 file", required=True)
@click.option('--prefix', help="e.g. ASSCTG", required=True)
@click.option('--output', help="Keep GFF3 file", required=True)
def run(gff3, prefix, output):
    print("Hello")
    with open(output, "w") as out_handle:
        for rec in GFF.parse(gff3):

            for count, feature in enumerate(rec.features):
                print("count", count)
                print(feature)
                print(feature.qualifiers.get("Name"))
                print(feature.sub_features)
                print(feature.sub_features[0].qualifiers.get("Name"))
                print("!!!!change")
                feature.qualifiers["ID"] = prefix + str(count).zfill(6)


                print(feature.sub_features[0].qualifiers["ID"])
                id_extension =  feature.sub_features[0].qualifiers["ID"][0].split('.')[1]
                feature.sub_features[0].qualifiers["ID"] = prefix + str(count).zfill(6) + '.' + id_extension
                print(feature.sub_features[0].qualifiers["Parent"])
                print("-----------")

            GFF.write([rec], out_handle)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Input file:

```
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    gene    7015    29794   0.01    -   .   ID=g1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    mRNA    7015    29794   0.01    -   .   ID=g1.t1;Parent=g1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    transcription_end_site  7015    7015    .   -   .   Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    three_prime_utr 7015    8531    0.2 -   .   ID=g1.t1.3UTR1;Parent=g1.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    7015    8747    .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon1;Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  8532    8534    .   -   0   Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 8532    8747    0.31    -   0   ID=g1.t1.CDS1;Parent=g1.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  8748    9191    0.49    -   .   Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 9192    9342    0.66    -   1   ID=g1.t1.CDS2;Parent=g1.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    9192    9342    .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon2;Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  9343    9915    0.58    -   .   Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 9916    10006   0.71    -   2   ID=g1.t1.CDS3;Parent=g1.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    9916    10006   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon3;Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  10007   10101   0.74    -   .   Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 10102   10201   0.78    -   0   ID=g1.t1.CDS4;Parent=g1.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    10102   10201   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon4;Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  10202   10712   0.8 -   .   Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 10713   11107   0.11    -   2   ID=g1.t1.CDS5;Parent=g1.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    10713   11107   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon5;Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  11108   11569   0.07    -   .   Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 11570   12151   0.09    -   2   ID=g1.t1.CDS6;Parent=g1.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    11570   12151   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon6;Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  12152   12588   0.34    -   .   Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 12589   12717   0.39    -   2   ID=g1.t1.CDS7;Parent=g1.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    12589   12717   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon7;Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  12718   12789   0.42    -   .   Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 12790   13075   0.39    -   0   ID=g1.t1.CDS8;Parent=g1.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    12790   13075   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon8;Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  13076   14832   0.51    -   .   Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 14833   15009   0.39    -   0   ID=g1.t1.CDS9;Parent=g1.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    14833   15009   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon9;Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  15010   15278   0.59    -   .   Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 15279   15415   0.56    -   2   ID=g1.t1.CDS10;Parent=g1.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    15279   15415   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon10;Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  15416   15487   0.58    -   .   Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 15488   15612   0.96    -   1   ID=g1.t1.CDS11;Parent=g1.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    15488   15612   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon11;Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  15613   15706   0.96    -   .   Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 15707   15957   0.98    -   0   ID=g1.t1.CDS12;Parent=g1.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    15707   15958   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon12;Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    start_codon 15955   15957   .   -   0   Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    five_prime_utr  15958   15958   0.99    -   .   ID=g1.t1.5UTR1;Parent=g1.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    five_prime_utr  27458   28250   0.37    -   .   ID=g1.t1.5UTR2;Parent=g1.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    27458   28250   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon13;Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    five_prime_utr  29272   29794   0.08    -   .   ID=g1.t1.5UTR3;Parent=g1.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    29272   29794   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon14;Parent=g1.t1;
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    transcription_start_site    29794   29794   .   -   .   Parent=g1.t1;
```

Output file:

```
##gff-version 3
##sequence-region NbV1Ch08 1 129222376
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    gene    7015    29794   0.01    -   .   ID=ACTG000000
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    mRNA    7015    29794   0.01    -   .   ID=ACTG000000.t1;Parent=g1,ACTG000000
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    transcription_end_site  7015    7015    .   -   .   Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    three_prime_utr 7015    8531    0.2 -   .   ID=g1.t1.3UTR1;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    7015    8747    .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon1;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  8532    8534    .   -   0   Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 8532    8747    0.31    -   0   ID=g1.t1.CDS1;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  8748    9191    0.49    -   .   Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 9192    9342    0.66    -   1   ID=g1.t1.CDS2;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    9192    9342    .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon2;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  9343    9915    0.58    -   .   Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 9916    10006   0.71    -   2   ID=g1.t1.CDS3;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    9916    10006   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon3;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  10007   10101   0.74    -   .   Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 10102   10201   0.78    -   0   ID=g1.t1.CDS4;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    10102   10201   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon4;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  10202   10712   0.8 -   .   Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 10713   11107   0.11    -   2   ID=g1.t1.CDS5;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    10713   11107   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon5;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  11108   11569   0.07    -   .   Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 11570   12151   0.09    -   2   ID=g1.t1.CDS6;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    11570   12151   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon6;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  12152   12588   0.34    -   .   Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 12589   12717   0.39    -   2   ID=g1.t1.CDS7;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    12589   12717   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon7;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  12718   12789   0.42    -   .   Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 12790   13075   0.39    -   0   ID=g1.t1.CDS8;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    12790   13075   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon8;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  13076   14832   0.51    -   .   Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 14833   15009   0.39    -   0   ID=g1.t1.CDS9;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    14833   15009   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon9;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  15010   15278   0.59    -   .   Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 15279   15415   0.56    -   2   ID=g1.t1.CDS10;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    15279   15415   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon10;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  15416   15487   0.58    -   .   Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 15488   15612   0.96    -   1   ID=g1.t1.CDS11;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    15488   15612   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon11;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    intron  15613   15706   0.96    -   .   Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    CDS 15707   15957   0.98    -   0   ID=g1.t1.CDS12;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    15707   15958   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon12;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    start_codon 15955   15957   .   -   0   Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    five_prime_utr  15958   15958   0.99    -   .   ID=g1.t1.5UTR1;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    five_prime_utr  27458   28250   0.37    -   .   ID=g1.t1.5UTR2;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    27458   28250   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon13;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    five_prime_utr  29272   29794   0.08    -   .   ID=g1.t1.5UTR3;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    exon    29272   29794   .   -   .   ID=g1.t1.exon14;Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
NbV1Ch08    AUGUSTUS    transcription_start_site    29794   29794   .   -   .   Parent=g1.t1,ACTG000000.t1
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Removing the old id from 'Parent`:

```
for subfeature in feature.sub_features:
    subfeature.qualifiers["Parent"].pop()
```

Chromosome name:

```
 for rec in GFF.parse(gff3):
            chrID = rec.id
```